# RuntimeException: Unable to create output dir: /storage/emulated/0/app_spoon-screenshots

Tags: android, ui-testing, spoon, barista

I am setting up Spoon for Android UI Testing using the [gradle-spoon-plugin](https://github.com/jaredsburrows/gradle-spoon-plugin) using the Spoon 2.0.0 snapshot. My project is set up using Android Gradle plug-in 3.0.1.

When taking screenshots via `spoonRule.screenshot(activity, "hello")`, I get this RuntimeException:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create output dir: /storage/emulated/0/app_spoon-screenshots
at com.squareup.spoon.SpoonRule.createDir(SpoonRule.java:167)
at com.squareup.spoon.SpoonRule.createDir(SpoonRule.java:164)
at com.squareup.spoon.SpoonRule.createDir(SpoonRule.java:164)
at com.squareup.spoon.SpoonRule.obtainDirectory(SpoonRule.java:108)
at com.squareup.spoon.SpoonRule.screenshot(SpoonRule.java:66)
```

Things work fine if I run it on a Nexus 4 API 19 emulator but it does not work on a Pixel 2 API 27 emulator. Permissions have changed a bunch from 19 to 27 so this is not totally unexpected.

I've tried most of the advice currently available including adding a manifest in my `androidTest` directory that grants the read and write external storage (with and without the `maxSdkVersion`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="tv.twitch.android.test">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="18"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="18"/>

    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test.uiautomator.v18"/>

</manifest>
```

I see these permissions being merged into my final manifest of my app's AndroidManifest (unsure how to check the test app's manifest) in both cases.

I've tried granting permissions via UIAutomator to both the app and test package:

```
val device = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation())
device.executeShellCommand("pm grant tv.twitch.android.test android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")
device.executeShellCommand("pm grant tv.twitch.android.debug android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")
device.executeShellCommand("pm grant tv.twitch.android.test android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")
device.executeShellCommand("pm grant tv.twitch.android.debug android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")
```

This outputs a `Permission denied` to Logcat and results in the same exception above.

If I try leveraging `GrantPermissionRule` like:

```
@get:Rule var runtimePermissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
```

I get a different exception:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Failed to grant permissions, see logcat for details
at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
at android.support.test.runner.permission.PermissionRequester.requestPermissions(PermissionRequester.java:110)
at android.support.test.rule.GrantPermissionRule$RequestPermissionStatement.evaluate(GrantPermissionRule.java:108)

GrantPermissionCallable: Permission: android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE cannot be granted!
```

Removing `Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and leaving just the read one gets us back to the original exception: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create output dir: /storage/emulated/0/app_spoon-screenshots`

Running from within Android Studio or on the command-line using `gradle-spoon-plugin` doesn't affect any of the above.

Looking at the permissions my app and test app are granted in Settings, I see my app has Storage permission but my test app (tv.twitch.android.test) does not have any permissions requested.

I also tried using the [Barista](https://github.com/SchibstedSpain/Barista#runtime-permissions) library:

```
PermissionGranter.allowPermissionsIfNeeded(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
```

With no luck their either.

Updates:

I tried making my test app target SDK version 22 in hopes it would get write permissions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="tv.twitch.android.test">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22"
        tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test.uiautomator.v18"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

</manifest>
```

Via Gradle (`./gradlew spoon`) I tried configuring the gradle-spoon-plugin to request all permissions:

```
spoon {
    // Grant all runtime permissions during installation on Marshmallow and above devices.
    grantAll = true
}
```

With no luck. And I even tried using Spoon library version 1.3.1 to no avail as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My issue was caused by an external library merging in the maxSdkVersion with the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. To get around this I removed the attribute and re-added the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. This is only needed for my application manifest and not the test application manifest.

```
<!-- Strip away maxSdkVersion -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
                 tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"/>

<!-- Add the permission with no maxSdkVersion defined -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Then you can build, grant permissions, and run the tests:

```
# Uninstall existing APKs and install our app APK and test APK
./gradlew uninstallAll installDebug installDebugAndroidTest

# List all APKs installed with adb shell 'pm list packages -f'
# Grant the app APK write and read to external storage permissions
adb shell pm grant gg.mark.debug android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
adb shell pm grant gg.mark.debug android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

export APK=build/outputs/apk/debug/debug.apk
export TEST_APK=build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/debug-androidTest.apk

# TEST_APK and APK are positional arguments so keep them in this order
# Disable GIF generation because it's slow
java -jar spoon-runner-2.0.0.jar --debug --disable-gif "$TEST_APK" "$APK"
```

The `pm grant` commands will fail if the permissions for your app are not set up properly **in merged AndroidManifest.xml**. Make sure those commands succeed!

Answer (score 0):

First, try to find `SystemSetting->YOUR_APP->Permission` on Pixel2 (API27), check whether the external storage is disable.

The permissions of `EXTERNAL_STORAGE`(both `WRITE` and `READ`) are required in runtime after API23 (Android 6+). You should check permission and notify user to enable in system configure. see [Request App Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Of course the normal apps don't have permission to grant their permissions as usual with `pm grant ...`.

An unrecommended solution is make the whole app target on API22. But the correct way also is that check permission and notify user.

Comment: In settings, my app is properly requesting Storage permissions but the Test app is not which is likely the issue. I am unsure if the test app should be showing a request permission dialog like the documentation you linked?

Comment: @Mark yes, the permission dialog is custom dialog, not system. The way in app indicating users to enable their permissions is developer part duty (in google eyes). You should test whether work if enable your app permission in Pixel2 system config(not your app manifest). Or make TargetApi = 22 to confirm whether is this reason really.

Comment: Sorry for doesn't see that `properly requesting Storage permissions`. Did you try set TargetApi to 22?